# What caused the spike in usage of "error" around 1537?

Tags: etymology

I was looking up the usage of "erroneous" which then turned to searching for "error". There was a sudden intense spike in usage between 1537 - 1541, specifically in American English. See [Ngram view for "Error"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erroneous%2C+error&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).

Any idea why?

Comment: There are a few documents in the date range for which the date is wrong, specifically docs published by government organizations that didn’t exist at the time, like the Massachusetts state legislature.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret this. If I click the 1965–2019 results, I get a list of hits that's far more extensive than those listed for 1500–1538. Either the detailed results are not representative of the actual data, or something else is going on. Is it possible, for instance, that one source from 1500 contains thousands of entries, while from the hundreds of sources from the last 50 years, each only contains a few entries?

Comment: @Xanne has it. I tried an experiment and [this NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&content=concrete%2Cradiation%2Cerror&year_start=1500&case_insensitive=on&year_end=1700&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cconcrete%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconcrete%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BConcrete%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCONCRETE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cradiation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bradiation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRadiation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRADIATION%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cerror%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Berror%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BError%3B%2Cc0) shows similar spikes for "concrete" and "radiation". There are classification errors.

Comment: @BoldBen The publication date of the documents is wrong.

Comment: One hit for 'concrete' (a few years *later*) turns out to be an OCR misreading of 'contrite'. I wonder if the translations of the bible at the time are the main source of all the hits for 'error'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian There are other occurrences of "concrete" returned by the NGRAM from documents of the Massachsetts state legislature the true dates of which seem to be 1950s or 60s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost certainly didn't spike.

Google Books is not comprehensive for any point in time, and in particular works from that time period are relatively few and prone to OCR errors due to changes in type. A number of instances of *error* indeed appear to be erroneous OCR of Greek or Latin texts.

Furthermore, works are not always accurately dated, and the effects of errors will be magnified owing to the smaller set of overall works. Clicking through to either word shows numerous obvious metadata errors, from an aerospace manual from the Society of Automotive Engineers dated at 1542 to a U.S. Federal Maritime Commission Informal Docket from 1987 marked as 1500.

What you are seeing then is the effect of an oversampling of government and academic texts, which are probably more likely to use words like *error* or *erroneous* compared to all publications, and some sort of flaw in the indexing process whereby a huge array of mid-20th century texts are dated to the 1500s.

Comment: It would not be particularly surprising if there were a spike in "**error erroneous**" Henry VIII had declared himself the Supreme Head of the Church of England and dismissed the authority of the Pope and siezed all the property of the Catholic Church. The religious argument had been going on for a few years, and in 1538 Henry VIII was excommunicated. During this time there was a lot of writing by each side, both of whom called the other heretics. The words "**error**" and "**erroneous**" would have been high on the list of insults used in the rejection of doctrines and dogma.